# systemd env vars from an executable script

Tags: linux, environment-variables, systemd

I have the following systemd service file:

```
[Unit]  
Description=My description  

[Service]  
Type=simple  
User=myuser  
ExecStart=/path/to/my/start_script.sh  
ExecStop=/path/to/my/stop_script.sh  
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID  
KillMode=process  
Restart=on-failure  
RestartSec=30s  

[Install]  
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My ***start_script.sh*** is used to start a java application BUT I need to get some variables from an executable ksh script ***custom_script.sh***.

I tried the following systemd params with no success:

- ExecStartPre
- EnvironmentFile

Is there a way to make it work?

Thank you in advance heroes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have the variables from `custom_script.sh` accessible from your Java process, you'll have to insert them into the environment somehow, in a way that systemd will be pleased with. The [docs for the `EnvironmentFile=` directive](http://0pointer.de/public/systemd-man/systemd.exec.html#Environment=) say that any line that is not a parameter assignment statement with an `=` sign will be ignored. So we need to take your script and cook it down so that all we have left are the variables after running it.

What you can do is create an auxiliary "distillery" service that sources your `custom_script.sh` file and prints every value in the environment to another file called `custom_script.env`. Then you can provide the "distilled" environment file to the Java process in the `EnvironmentFile` directive.

So if your original service adds `After=` and `Requires=` like this,

```
[Unit]  
Description=My description  
After=custom-script-distillery
Requires=custom-script-distillery

[Service]  
Type=simple  
User=myuser  
EnvironmentFile=/path/to/my/custom_script.env
ExecStart=/path/to/my/start_script.sh  
ExecStop=/path/to/my/stop_script.sh  
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID  
KillMode=process  
Restart=on-failure  
RestartSec=30s  

[Install]  
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then the distillery could look like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=My service to distill custom_script.sh to an EnvironmentFile

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'set -o allexport; source /path/to/my/custom_script.sh; set +o allexport; unset IFS; set | grep -v "^BASH" > /path/to/my/custom_script.env'
```

Comment: I ended up by doing this:
`ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'set -a && source custom_script.sh && start_script.sh '`
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that's a great idea, just source it and go.